# Rails 3 Turning Data Into Diagrams

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, draw, diagram

my application has a tournament/competition system where players face off against each other. I was wondering if any solutions existed that could turn the data from my Matchmaking table into a diagram.

For instance if I had a double knockout tournament structure persisted in my database would there be a way to take that raw data and turn it into something like this:

[image: Knockout Tournament Diagram]

I'm thinking I might have to use HTML 5 canvas or something for this, but I was hoping there would be a less manual approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/) in your application to generate pictures from the data you have stored in your database. It's not Ruby, but surely you can call 3rd party programs with it.

Your Ruby program would have to describe the graph data in a DOT file, you can see its description here: http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language

Comment: This seems like a pretty good solution, I don't think it will be a problem passing the commands from my application to Graphviz and returning the SVG. Actually figuring out how to generate the DOT file will be the tricky part, but still seems like a much better option than canvas to me.

Comment: It is good to generate UML diagrams using graphviz(through railroady gem),but if you want to generate data flow diagrams to make prototype for actual flow ,it doesn't have any kind of feature to represent the same.